# Pass parameter to GET request in laravel tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-7, laravel-testing

In Laravel tests i want to **send a get request with some parameters** like this:

```php
        $response=$this->get(
            route('orders.payment.pay',['order'=>$order->id]),
            ['pay_type','payment_gateway']
        );
```

but when i run it, i have **`302`** **Error code in response**. But when use it like this it works correct:

```php
        $response=$this->get(
            route('orders.payment.pay',['order'=>$order->id]).'?pay_type=payment_gateway'
        );
```

Is there any way to pass parameter like first way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the signature of the `route` helper:

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
```

You should add any query parameters you want to the array or parameters you are passing to the `route` helper:

```
route('orders.payment.pay', [
    'order' => $order->id,
    'pay_type' => 'payment_gateway',
]);
```

Any parameter that is not substituted for a Route Parameter is appended as a query string parameter.